# FileVersionInfo.FileVersion returns ProductVersion?

Tags: c#, .net, getfileversion

I am trying to get the file version using C#:

```
string file = @"C:\somefile.dll";
Console.WriteLine(FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(file).FileVersion);
```

For most files this is fine, however for some i receive results that are different than the ones presented in the Windows file explorer.

See the attached image: the file version presented in windows is "0.0.0.0", however the one i get using FileVersion property is "000.000.000.000".

I've tried using different versions of the .NET (2, 3.5, 4) which give the same results.

Anyone else experienced this issue?

Thanks
Lior

[image]

Comment: what are your columns in your Windows Explorer image?  What is the first 'version' column and what's the second?

Comment: first one is File Version. second one is "Product Version".

Comment: In code i am getting FileVersion property the same as displayed in "Product Version" in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Windows Explorer are stripping leading 0s of the version parts.

Try creating an assembly with FileVersion 001.001.001.001, it will show as 1.1.1.1 in explorer. But your code would return the actual value (001.001.001.001).

EDIT:

Explorer will return 001.001.001.001 as **ProductVersion**, but only if *AssemblyInformationalVersion* isn't set, in which case it would return that as ProductVersion.

Comment: I've created an assembly with the suggested version. Indded, explorer shows it as "1.1.1.1" as both file version and product version.

Comment: Problem is some other APIs are stripping away these leading zeroes, failing some of the comparisons i was making between these and the FileVersion.

Comment: Virtual -1. Your answer is wrong. Version is not 001.001... it is actually 000.000.000.000. This is a string, see my answer.

Comment: @Aliostad 001 was just used an example to provide a test case. FileVersionInfo.FileVersion is also a string, and it refers to the file version seen in explorer (not product version). If one would want to replicate explorer's behaviour, one could convert it to an integer based Version object: new Version("000.000.000.000")

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, in WIN32 API (and the file metadata), product versions are defined as string but file versions are defined as integer while in .NET, all of them are defined as integer.

If you use reflector and inspect `FileVersionInfo` class, you can see that they are loaded differently:

```
 this.productVersion = GetFileVersionString(memIntPtr, string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format, new object[] { codepage, "ProductVersion" }))
```

But:

```
this.fileMajor = HIWORD(fixedFileInfo.dwFileVersionMS);
this.fileMinor = LOWORD(fixedFileInfo.dwFileVersionMS);
this.fileBuild = HIWORD(fixedFileInfo.dwFileVersionLS);
this.filePrivate = LOWORD(fixedFileInfo.dwFileVersionLS);
```

Comment: If they are defined as an integer in WIN32, how come the integer is converted to a string with leading zeroes? it should've been converted to the representation of the int in string.

Comment: You said it was product info and not file info (in the comments you said product info is the second one)

Comment: File Version in windows = "0.0.0.0", Product Version in windows = "000.000.000.000". In .NET they boh return "000.000.000.000". If according to WIN32, the File Version is made of INTs, where is it getting the trailing zeroes when retrieved in .NET? i would expect .NET to parse it to string as "0" and not "000".

Answer (score 0):

Two answers from 2011, each missing part of the picture.

Version information resources must contain [version information in *binary* form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource) and may also contain separate [version information in *string* form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/menurc/stringfileinfo-block).

The two are not constrained to match.
Indeed, the *string* forms are not even constrained to be numeric, and can have all kinds of arbitrary text stuff in them.

In this case, what was compiled into the DLL file was this:

- The *binary* form of the file version has four words of zeros, and `FileMajor`, `FileMinor`, `FileBuild`, and `FilePrivate` thus end up as four integers with value zero.
- The *string* form of the file version is literally the string "`000.000.000.000`" and that's what `FileVersion` comes out as.

It's not showing the product version as the file version.
It's showing the (free-format) file version *string*, not the (four 16-bit words) file version *numbers*.

The first added fun part is that the string form must match the current language and code page at runtime of the program reading the resource information out of the DLL.
As you can see from the doco, the mechanism permits (potentially) each language+codepage to have its own, translated, variant of the file version string; and the APIs pull out the one that matches.

The second added fun part is that the properties dialogue in Windows Explorer will only show the *binary* form of the file version.
It just ignores the *string* form entirely.
(This is an undocumented Explorer quirk; that you will however find mentioned in several exasperated Stack Overflow comments over the past decade since this question was asked.)
But the version information as read out by `Get-Item` in PowerShell or the `System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo` class in .NET will yield *both* the string and binary forms that are compiled into the DLL as separate sets of information.

PowerShell presents this as a `FileVersion` property that is a `System.String` object constructed from the string form compiled into the DLL and a `FileVersionRaw` property that is a `System.Version` object constructed from the binary, four 16-bit words, form compiled into the DLL.