# Reflection: assembly get version giving wrong version value

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies

I use the fallowing code to get the version of a set of assembles in windows GAC folder.

```
FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
                string productVersion = fvi.ProductVersion;
```

After running the above code I mannualy RightClick and get the version of the assemblies.
The version returned by `productVersion` is different to the value obtained manually, for **some of the assemblies**.
Any possible reason?

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460199/fileversioninfo-fileversion-returns-productversion

Comment: An example of the difference (expected vs actual) would help...

Comment: version returns is 15.0.xxxx.10000 , but actual version is 15.0.yyyy.1000. This happens when I installed an app of its xxxx version, then unstall it, then install the yyyy version of that app. After installing the yyyy version of the app, all the dlls supposed to be in yyyy version. When manually checking it is OK. But this mismatch happens when programmatic checking the version.

Comment: @David it seems similar, but not what I want.

Answer (score 4):

For the file version of an assembly object use:

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); // the current assembly

var version = assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Comment: this gives the result 15.0.0.0 which is not what I want. I want to get the product version which is 15.0.yyyy.1000

Comment: Luckily, it IS what i want :)