# FileVersionInfo retrieving incorrect file version

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have to retrieve values under details tab e.g, File version, Product Version for .dll and .exe files through C#. I'm using the following code for this.

```
     FileVersionInfo myFile = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo('Name of the file');
     //File Version
     string fileVersion = myFile.FileVersion;
```

The issue with this code is that it gives incorrect file version for some files. Details tab of these files shows different file version and code retrieves incorrect value. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Please help. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? What was the expected version (from Explorer) and what was the one you got?

Comment: I have found that computers rarely lie :) --- make absolutely sure that you are looking at the same file and values that your code is retrieving.

Comment: expected version(from Explorer) is 10.0.0.35 and i got 10.0.000.0035 i have checked many times. for the same file this issue has occured

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5460402/32746

Answer (score 1):

> expected version(from Explorer) is 10.0.0.35 and i got 10.0.000.0035

That's the same number.  The file version number appears in the native resource *twice*.  Something you can also see when you edit a version resource in a C++ program.  There's a human readable version with no restrictions on the format.  That's what you are reading, note how FileVersionInfo.FileVersion returns a *string*.

And there's a machine readable version, a 64-bit number.  With 16-bits each for the 4 parts.  Which is what Explorer is reading.  The corresponding properties are FileMajorPart, FileMinorPart, FileBuildPart and FilePrivatePart.  Note how they return an *int*.

ProductVersion has this too.

Comment: So to see if two are eqivalent, one should say `var fileVersionSeq = fileVersion.Split('.').Select(ushort.Parse);` and then use [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) to check all components up against the other sequence?

Comment: Why don't you just use the int properties instead of trying to parse it?  Parsing can fail.

Comment: Good idea. Then, going the other way: `string versionStringWithoutLeadingZeros = string.Join(".", myFile.FileMajorPart, myFile.FileMinorPart, myFile.FileBuildPart, myFile.FilePrivatePart);`

Answer (score 1):

You can get full application file version with the below approach

```cs
FileVersionInfo myFile = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo('Name of the file');
string fileVersion = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", myFile.FileMajorPart, 
                                                      myFile.FileMinorPart, 
                                                      myFile.FileBuildPart, 
                                                      myFile.FilePrivatePart)
```

Comment: In some cases this ^ works, but this `myFile.FileVersion` does't work...!